# Ubuntu Touchscreen on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro

Tags: touchscreen

Does anyone have any experience with Ubuntu running on the Yoga 2 Pro in terms of the functionality of the touchscreen?

Comment: Duplicate of [Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro](http://askubuntu.com/a/485632)

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying out Ubuntu via a live usb on the Yoga 13 right now.
The Yoga 2 Pro is the reboot of that device.

Anyway, the are no issues with the touchscreen for me on 13.10.
The buttons seem no smaller than they are in Windows, so there's that.
I haven't installed the driver to enable wifi, but purchased a $10 Edimax usb adapter that is doing the trick.

Pinch-to-zoom isn't there (bummer), but the [grab and drag addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/grab-and-drag/) makes it pleasant to navigate the Internet by touch.
There are addons like that for Chrome as well.

Comment: It is so easy to reenable the Wifi, just type `sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop` Then add that to the modprobe blacktĺist with:
`sudo su;
echo '#added to enable WiFi on Yoga 2 Pro'>/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf;
echo 'blacklist ideapad_laptop'>/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, see my guide: http://askubuntu.com/a/419212/34298

Comment: And the touchpad switch off and rotation is solved here: [Disable the touchpad on Yoga 2 Pro in tablet mode](http://askubuntu.com/q/450066)

Comment: I tested in *Chrome Version 41.0.2272.76 Ubuntu 14.10*: there the touchscreen works fine as expected even pinch to zoom works fine and all menues are the correct size

Answer (score 2):

The touchscreen is working, but it's not really practical.  Because of the extreme display resolution, the buttons are far too small to use a finger.  At 1080 they are a bit more functional.  Also in chrome the touchscreen can't do anything.

The onscreen keyboard "Onboard" works just fine, and is arguably a better touch keyboard than Windows 8.

So yes, the hardware is working perfectly.  But the user interface doesn't support it very well.  I'm hoping that this improves in the future.

Comment: Does scrolling work somehow (other than grabbing a tiny scrollbar)? Also, you could try KDE; nearly every graphical element can be scaled in KDE.

Comment: It is easy to change the font dpi to have a readeable size everywhere. see my guide: [How to adapt Ubuntu to a high-DPI resolution screen](http://askubuntu.com/q/472262)

Comment: I tested in *Chrome Version 41.0.2272.76 Ubuntu 14.10*: there the touchscreen works fine as expected even pinch to zoom works fine and all menues are the correct size

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on the Yoga 2 Pro and in KDE, I adjusted a few things and am very happy with that now. I don't really have any problems with the high resolution anymore, so instead of decreasing it, I can enjoy my full res.
The touchscreen works ok in normal laptop mode (I am not using (K)Ubuntu in tablet mode really, since I work in the terminal, but e.g. I can't scroll in firefox as in pushing the page up- or downwards. This kinda bugs me.

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 touch gestures. 1 is to double tap with 3 fingers to window switch. It's a bit hard for me to switch but you'll probably get the hang of it. And the second gesture is to hold three fingers on the screen. Now you can drag three fingers across the screen to drag the current window.
Some things to make things better for touchscreen are to keep the unity interface. Or use gnome 3 as it has something like the Mac OSX launchpad (Which is like the Unity dash). The best thing is to get Chrome. It lets you scroll with touchscreen. And as far as I know about emulated right clicks. Touching and holding the screen with 1 finger makes a right click menu appear, with buttons big enough for fingers. The Ubuntu touch keyboard and the touch keyboard for Chrome adds a good experience.
And the unity launcher on the left has buttons big enough for touchscreen. The dash looks like it's touchscreen optimized. Is that enough info?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 13.10 on the yoga pro, the touch screen is working but if you do not tweak the settings for the high resolution screen it is hard to navigate using the screen.

In addition to the hidpi problem that can partly be resolved, you will also have a problem when using the yoga in tablet mode. The keyboard is switched off but the touch pad is not. Moreover, if you rotate the screen 90 degrees, the touch screen is not rotated (you will have to change x configurations to solve this, have not done so myself yet).

Comment: The touchpad switch off and rotation is solved here: [Disable the touchpad on Yoga 2 Pro in tablet mode](http://askubuntu.com/q/450066)