# Rotate touchscreen and disable the touchpad on Yoga 2 Pro in rotated mode

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, function-keys

On my Lenovo Yoga 2 pro I installed Ubuntu 14.04 32bit and kept the installed Windows 8 on another partition.

In Windows, When you turn it into tablet mode, the keyboard **and touchpad** turns off so you don't accidently click on it at the back of the "tablet".

In ubuntu 14.04 only the keyboard turns off, but the touchpad stays active.
Not even the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> combination doesn't turn it off.

So far I can only disable it with

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

(and re-enable with 0)

I tried `xev` to get the keycode for <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> but pressing this combo generates no output. Turning the monitor to the back neither.

How can I disable the touchpad automatically when I rotate or turn the monitor on the back, and re-enable the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> Hotkey?

[screenshot of the Touchpad Off Button on F6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKfaS.jpg)

---

**UPDATE:**
After some weeks `sudo apt-get upgrade` <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> is working now, so there is only the question how to rotate the screen and how to disable the touchpad automatically when rotating the screen.

Comment: It might be possible to use ACPI hooks. With [thinkpad-scripts](https://github.com/martin-ueding/thinkpad-scripts), we do the same thing. See for example [the rotation hook](https://github.com/martin-ueding/thinkpad-scripts/blob/master/thinkpad-rotate-acpi-hook-1).

Comment: There might be a solution working out here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125476/how-do-i-find-out-the-emitted-keycode-of-fnf6

Comment: It is designed for the ThinkPad Yogas, but you might like to try out [spin](https://github.com/wdbm/spin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Info:

I think the Hotkey <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> works since some time If you install the latest Ubuntu updates.

---

### Rotate the screen and touchscreen input 180 degrees

create the script [`/usr/local/bin/rotate-screen.sh`](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/daa262e0229f6e398766)
(I enhanced that script there at gist so it rotates 90° also)

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script rotates the screen and touchscreen input 180 degrees, disables the touchpad, and enables the virtual keyboard
# And rotates screen back if the touchpad was disabled

isEnabled=$(xinput --list-props 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad' | awk '/Device Enabled/{print $NF}')

if [ $isEnabled == 1 ] 
then
    echo "Screen is turned upside down"
    xrandr -o inverted
    xinput set-prop 'ELAN Touchscreen' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
    xinput disable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
    # Remove hashtag below if you want pop-up the virtual keyboard  
    # onboard &
else
    echo "Screen is turned back to normal"
    xrandr -o normal
    xinput set-prop 'ELAN Touchscreen' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
    xinput enable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
    # killall onboard 
fi
```

and give it executable rights:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rotate-screen.sh
```

then

### 1.

create `*.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/`

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/rotate-screen.desktop
```

### 2.

Paste below text:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/un-reboot.png
Name=rotate-screen
Exec=/usr/local/bin/rotate-screen.sh
Categories=Utility;
```

Then run the script via the Unity launcher startmenu (type "rotate-screen")

### Source:

https://askubuntu.com/a/446125/34298

Answer (score 1):

I was in the exact same position, only on a Yoga 3. I found this thread and the **brilliant** answer by *rubo77*, so I've begun adapting it into a command line tool, so it's a little easier to control things exactly, and only toggle the things you want. It's still work in progress at the moment, but the core functionality is there and working.

Repo: https://github.com/RealOrangeOne/yoga-pal

(Installation instructions can be found [Here](https://github.com/RealOrangeOne/yoga-pal/blob/master/README.md))

Extra note, if your laptop has a hardware button for rotating the screen (on mine it's on the right hand side), you can bind that to call commands, meaning you can restore it's intended functionality. It can also be used in replacement for *rubo*'s script inside a desktop entry if you would prefer to run it that way.

Comment: Looks nice, but you should add some instructions for the installation here.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout this repo: https://github.com/pfps/yoga-laptop

It fixes wifi issue and not working special keys. Screen rotation is WIP.