# Access the gyroscope and accellerator on Yoga 2 Pro

Tags: drivers, kernel, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro and would like to get the gyroscope running.

But how should I start accessing it and including it in my system?
(Here I made a [dump of `lspci -vvv` and `lsmod` on my Lenovo Yoga 2](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/dde2617f9edf795d0ee8))

I would like to automatically rotate the screen when I rotate the laptop.

---

I already have successfully created a script, that **manually** rotates the screen with the
keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+F5 (see https://askubuntu.com/a/485632/34298)

---

Maybe there is a way to adapt this script? https://gist.github.com/emiller/6488449

---

I also tried to add the [autorotate PPA from Karol Krizka](http://www.krizka.net/projects/autorotate/installation-ubuntu/) and install it:

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kkrizka/thinkpad-x61t/ubuntu lucid main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kkrizka-auto-rotate.list

#Update apt-get’s package list:
sudo apt-get update

#Install the script and necessary packages:
sudo apt-get install wacom-tools python-xrandr autorotate
```

But It seems like there is a dependency problem:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 autorotate : Depends: python-central (>= 0.6.11) but it is not installable
 python-xrandr : Depends: python-central (>= 0.6.11) but it is not installable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution but for me it ended the search for one:

I was satisfied when I found out [how to rotate it manually](https://askubuntu.com/a/485685/34298)

Answer (score 1):

Add the [autorotate PPA from Karol Krizka](http://www.krizka.net/projects/autorotate/installation-ubuntu/)

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kkrizka/thinkpad-x61t/ubuntu lucid main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kkrizka-auto-rotate.list

#Update apt-get’s package list:
sudo apt-get update

#Install the script and necessary packages:
sudo apt-get install wacom-tools python-xrandr autorotate

# You can have the auto-rotate.py damon to start with GDM, so it will be available to all users, even during login. This is done by adding the following line to the end of the /etc/gdm/Init/Default file before the exit 0 command:
auto-rotate.py&

# Restart GDM to start the script:
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart
```

Swivel down your screen into the tablet mode, and tilt it at around 45 degrees to test if everything is working.

If you also want to rotate it manually, [Follow the general instructions for setting up buttons for manual rotation.](http://www.krizka.net/projects/autorotate/manualrotate/)

### Note

This doesn't work on m Ubuntu 14.04