# Lenovo Twist - automatic onboard keyboard in tablet mode

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, onboard

When I switch my Twist to tablet mode, the touchscreen isn't deactivated (the cursor jumps around), the screen isn't rotated 180 degrees and the onboard keyboard doesn't pop up when I'm in an input field.

Looking around, I've found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450066/rotate-touchscreen-and-disable-the-touchpad-on-yoga-2-pro-in-rotated-mode?newreg=7b64cba50ccf4dd2beab54e78b4a9054) and I can now rotate the screen, activate the virtual keyboard and disable the touchpad when I call the script, but unfortunately, I can't seem to get the virtual keyboard to only pop up when needed (it's always there).

Is there a way to do all this (preferably automatically), like a driver update? If not, how do I modify the script to do something similar?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Twist. Here's some info from dmidecode:

```
BIOS Information
    Version: GDET90WW (1.50 )

System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 3347CTO
    Version: ThinkPad Twist
    SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_3347CTO
    Family: ThinkPad Twist
```