# Screen resolution not scaling properly during boot up

Tags: resolution, scaling

I have a problem that is rather annoying during the boot up of Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

I dual boot with windows 7 and when I get to the OS selection bit, there is a nice fat black border around the edge of the screen where the resolution is not scaling properly.

I have installed super boot manager and burg, which are running just fine and I also have correctly set the screen resolution to 1920x1080.  The resolution works fine and is being picked up correctly, it is just that it is not scaling properly at all, regardless of what resolution I pick.

I am using a HP2311x monitor (1920x1080 native) on a Nvidia GTX660 and connected via a DVI cable.

Is there any possible way I can correctly scale my resolution, during the boot up process.

What is worse is that it correctly scales during installation of the DVD ROM.

So why does it scale correctly off a DVD during install and completely fails once the OS is installed correctly and all the drivers updated and working just fine.

Comment: did you solve this? if so, please provide the solution as answer here

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter the command

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now a text file opens. Find the following lines:

```
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Remove the hash # before the last line, because that turns it into an active line. Then change the resolution into the one you want, for example 1366 x 768:
GRUB_GFXMODE=1366x768

Save the modified file and close it. Now copy/paste the following line into the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Press Enter and if prompted, submit your password. Please note that the password will remain invisible, not even asterisks will show, which is normal.

source: [Make your Grub boot menu pretty - Easy Linux tips project](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/beautifygrub)