# Where can I customize window sizes of Notifications in KDE?

Tags: kde, fonts, notification-area

On my 13 inch 3200x1800px screen if I click on an icon in the bottom right corner the popping up window is far too small:

[image]

How can I change the window width of those popup notifications?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, or to do with your specified DPI, but those tray icons are tiny! [Oh, I just saw your other question.]

Answer (score -1):

First, I would restart.

if that doesn't resolve the issue, try
chaning the file in ~/[.kde|.kde4]/share/config rename kde.notifyrc & knotifyrc

and restarting.
That should reset the notifications.

Comment: I have no kde.notifyrc on my whole system. And I don't think I have to reset it. this is a fresh install and the problem comes from the hi-res screen resolution and the fact I changed the global font-dpi to 230 from 96.