# I just installed Ubuntu on my Yoga 2 pro and I am looking to manually adjust the screen resolution

Tags: resolution, screen, lenovo

This was my installation method. Strung together from various sources.

[Steps I followed to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo Yoga 2 pro](http://peaceplantsandpushups.com/2014/03/12/22/)

Comment: Search for 'settings' and open an app called System settings or something like that. There you can find a "Displays" section..

Comment: Here you find a complete guide, How to install [Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro](http://askubuntu.com/a/485632)

Answer (score 0):

The package you are looking for is `xrandr` (should be installed by default).

To see the help :

```
xrandr --help
```

To read the manual :

```
man xrandr
```

---

You can change your screen resolution with :

```
xrandr --fb <width>x<height>
```