# No more grub menu

Tags: grub2, lubuntu, boot-repair, windows-10

I can't access the grub menu anymore, my computer directly boots into Windows 10.
I tried a `boot-repair` but it didn't fix the problem.

Here is the pastebin link:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13006892/

Any idea how to make the grub menu reappear?

---

**EDIT**

I just installed `easyuefi` as suggested by 金潇泽. 
Here it a screenshot:

[image]

How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you turn off your 'Fast Startup' in your Windows? In Windows 8.1, you can go to :

> "Power Options", "Choose what the power buttons do", "Change settings that are currently unavailable", uncheck the "Turn on fast startup".
>
> Maybe you want to disable hibernate too. (In some case it has to disable too)

Try to disable "Secure Boot" in your BIOS. (In some case it has to disable too). Because it might different from one OEM with another.

But, based on your boot-repair report, it seems boot loader not found in your hd (dev/sda), so, it seems boot-repair can't install the grub. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub).

Comment: just deactivated the fast startup and secure boot was already disabled. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just try using [easyuefi](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html/) on win10 or efibootmgr on ubuntu to manage uefi boot order or something else about uefi options.

```
 $ efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,002A,0001,0028,0029,0002,0003,0004
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001  Windows Boot Manager
Boot0002* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive
Boot0003* UEFI:Removable Device
Boot0004* UEFI:Network Device
Boot0028  UEFI: IP4 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Boot0029  UEFI: IP6 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Boot002A* ubuntu
```

Or you can try press F12 or F2 to choose the OS while booting.

If all above doesn't work ,you may check your bios settings like what the first answer says.

---

It seems everything is OK judging from your screenshot.The only thing you should do is to change the position of ubuntu to the top and reboot.

Comment: When i type `efibootmgr` nothing is displayed.

Comment: I just installed `easyuefi`. How to use it?