# "Unable to install GRUB" error on installation with RAID 1, cannot set boot flag on any partition

Tags: server, grub2, raid, bootloader

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 Server on my fresh new PC which is intended to be a server. I am trying to install it with RAID 1 since I have 2 SSD with 500 GB. I have managed to get in the installation to GRUB bootloader and on 50% of bootloader installation I got the error:

> Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda. Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed. This is fatal error.

I have also noticed when I followed tutorial, that when I created partitions (swap, + RAID partition) on both disks that there was not option for primary/logical partition. But I have managed to create both partitions for both disks and I have managed to create special partition.

What I have also noticed is that I can't flag bootable on any of non swappable partition, when I chose Ext4.

I have tried to swap SSD SATA cables and nothing helped. This also happen with 16.04.

Thank you.

EDIT: What I think is that I need to do something in BIOS (don't know what), so I can enable option during installation to choose between primary and logical partition. Maybe then I will be able to install GRUB bootloader. The problem is that I am not sure if I need to do something in BIOS, and if I do, what?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. What command are you using to install `grub` ? and also please add the output of `fdisk -l`

Comment: I am not using commands. I am just following step by step in installation.

Comment: I have edited my question so you can have (I hope) better overview of my problem.

Comment: check this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub