# grub-install fails when trying to install Kubuntu on the entire disk

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

### Issue

I'm having trouble installing an Ubuntu flavor with the Guided partitioning.

> grub-install failed on /dev/sda

I've tried almost every tip I've found online and also related posts on this community and nothing has worked so far.

Raleted posts that didn't work for me:

- [Wrong Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub)

### what I've tried

1. Manual partitioning (swap, efi, /boot, /)
2. Guided partitioning
3. Wipe the entire disk and manual partition it as well as guided
4. Assign kernel to and old GRUB
5. Boot-Repair tool in try mode
6. Disable Fast Boot & re install
7. Disable Secure boot & re install

Nothing has worked so far, I can't realize why this is happening since I'm wiping the entire disk

> This has happened to me previously when I tried to install another flavor as well.

PS: I'm not trying to make it dual boot, just run Kubuntu on my entire disk.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: when you say you've wiped the disk, I am assuming that you have formatted it as GPT in the live session and do nothing else before rebooting and starting the installer.  Beyond that, could your installation media be invalid?  Maybe the ISO was corrupted or there was an issue flashing it to the USB.  Does your installation media pass integrity checks?

Comment: I believe so, I'll try to burn it again, but this error occurs on other flavors as well

Comment: I burned it again but nothing has changed `grub-install /dev/sda failed`