# Ubuntu 14.04 & Lenovo Yoga 2 pro screen resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, display, lenovo, hdmi

I've recently installed 14.04 on my yoga and it is running great so far!

Since this laptop has a 3200x1800 resolution and a lot of apps i use do not scale well i am using 1920x1080 resolution with 1x scaling. Everything still looks crisp and sharp, no complaints on that front.

My issue is i have to have a custom script loaded when ubuntu starts that changes the resolution from 3200 to 1920 so when i log in i have to wait for the resolution to change before i log in or else the resolution will stay at 3200 and then i have to change it manually.

My question is, is there any way to remove the actual 3200x1800 resolution from even being an option?

Another small issue i run into is, i use an external monitor(1920x1080) sometimes and when i unlpug the hdmi cable, my desktop on my laptop screen reverts back to 3200 resolution.

I basically want to fool ubuntu into thinking that the highest resolution to choose from is 1920x1080. Is this possible?

Sorry for the long winded question :)

Answer (score 1):

Stripping down the resolution to 1920px might not be the best solution.

You can easily adapt Ubuntu to such a high resolution: [Adapt Ubuntu to a high-DPI resolution screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472262)

There is a new new option since Ubuntu 14.04:
In `System Settings`->`Displays`  Look for `"Scale for menu and title bars."`

I solved some more issues in my [Guide for the Yoga 2 Pro](https://askubuntu.com/a/485632/34298)

Also you can [Adjust Firefox and Thunderbird to a High DPI touchscreen display (retina)](https://askubuntu.com/q/487032)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that method before. Unfortunately a lot of the applications i use for work do not scale properly at that resolution and scaling setting.

Comment: @RjPiston: There is a new option now

Comment: Thanks @rubo77, unfortunately, a lot of apps i use still don't scale well. I've resorted to keeping my resolution at 1920x1080 for the time being.

Comment: Which APPS? May be we find solutions for those too

Comment: Chrome, hangouts, Thunderbird, firefox Wunderlist, Unity Tweak tool just to name a few. thanks!

Comment: Also the kingsoft office apps

Comment: Some are fixed here: [Adjust Firefox and Thunderbird to a High DPI touchscreen display (retina)](http://askubuntu.com/q/487032)

Comment: I'm on 14.10 on a Dell XPS 15 (same resolution) and I, too, resorted to using 1920x1080 for the same reasons. 3200x1800 is just NOT usable right now, ESPECIALLY with multiple monitors (my external is 2560x1440). I have tried VERY hard to get high dpi working, but Chrome (chromium is getting closer), Firefox, Hipchat, Unity itself do not have a way to set scaling factor per monitor, which is necessary when you have two completely different resolutions. Hopefully 15.04 comes closer. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Did you try xrandr? It has some decent examples in the howto for different dpi on two screens