# Strange glitches on initial login

Tags: unity, wireless, 14.04, fonts, lenovo

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 with full-disk encryption, my computer boots up fairly quickly. When I first log in to my account, four strange glitches happen all at the same time, and all fixed by logging out and back in.

1. The wrong font is displayed in window menus and the clock in the status bar.
2. The display resolution does not adjust to its configured value.
3. The menu bars for windows are sometimes displayed under the title, although they are configured to display in the title bar.
4. The wifi speed is limited and inconsistent, which may be a different glitch as I do have an Intel Wireless 7260N, which has been reported to have problems in 14.04.

Strangely enough, numbers 1 and 2 happened in my previous install, 13.10, but only after booting from a live USB. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro (the Intel i5 processor variant.)

**EDIT:** I've found the problem. What seems to be happening is that I was using the acpi_backlight=vendor flag to start the kernel, which used to be needed to show the screen, but is no longer needed, and so including it was freaking out the system. Removing this flag from the grub configuration solved the problem (and all of its side effects.)

Comment: Sounds like it could be a graphics driver issue. Do you see any warnings or errors in `/var/log/kern.log` or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` or `~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: @bain they all had several warnings: [kern.log warnings](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7449919/) [Xorg.0.log warnings](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7449922/) [xsession errors](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7449940/)

Comment: so Yoga 2 Pro and Ubuntu 14.04 don't need the fix like 13.10 anymore? http://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro?