# Lenovo Yoga 2 Ubuntu 14.04 occasionanal blank screen

Tags: 14.04, suspend, lenovo

I have a new Lenovo Yoga 2 with Ubuntu 14.04. On every 3rd or 4th boot, the screen goes completely blank after the grub screen and the backlight seems to ramp up to maximum intensity (I see a faint growing white glow). I can hear the drums beat for the login, but nothing shows up on the screen. This seems to be random--I cannot figure out a way to bypass this without rebooting several times. It also seems to randomly happen while waking up from suspend.

I have the acpi_backlight = vendor in the grub boot line. This does not seem to make a difference as I get this random behaviour with and without the boot flag.

--prasanna

Comment: While my Yoga 2 pro with 14.04 is booting ok so far every time, I do get a blank _grey_ screen upon waking from sleep, which is unresponsive with every key combination except F9 which actually does work by blanking the screen to black, and again to bring up the grey screen; I am forced to reboot to reset.  This has happened so far for kernels: 3.13.0-28-generic & 3.13.0-29-generic and I am not using the *acpi_backlight* flag.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same on 14.04. On 13.10 it worked well. I can't fix it, but there is a little workaround. When screen goes black press the F9 key (switch the screen off), close the lid  and don't move the laptop*. It will go to sleep. Then open it and wake it up by pressing any key. My Yoga 2 Pro wakes up with the screen working fine.

- Y2P has a movement sensor, so if you move it when it goes to sleep it fail to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, also on 14.04 and I can't fix it either, but there is a simple work-around:

**Just close the lid so the screen gets turned off and reopen it.**

This seems to reset the graphic-card driver and the screen is working again (sometimes you have to do this several times to work).

I hope, I find out a cleaner solution, or a simpler workaround with just a [Keyboard-shortcut to reset the graphic card driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507884/keyboard-shortcut-to-reset-the-graphic-card-driver)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in the beginning too, but it seems to be fixed in Ubuntu 14.04 by now.

My Kernel: `uname -rp`

```
 3.14.1-031401-generic i686
```

Answer (score -1):

If your screen acts strange after suspend, it's usually enough to switch to console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and back to graphics again (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>).