# Keyboard-shortcut to reset the graphic card driver

Tags: suspend, intel-graphics, screensaver

I would like to fix the on my [Lenovo Yoga 2 Ubuntu 14.04 occasionanal blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471943/lenovo-yoga-2-ubuntu-14-04-occasionanal-blank-screen). Since the only workaround is to close the lid and reopen it, I guess the graphic-card gets a hang-up that is gone if the card is turned off and on again.

How can I turn off and on the screen like closing and opening the lid does on the commandline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has answered this, yet, it shows up at the top of a Google search, try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

What has worked for me is just moving my finger on the mouse pad, then once the screen flashes, click the mouse twice.  When that does not work, I use the above.  I did try the various script changes suggested elsewhere, they did not work, which is why I did not repost them.