# Wireless-N 7260 with Ubuntu 14.04 not working

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04, windows-8

I just bought a Lenovo Yoga 2 notebook and 2 days after buying I decided to install Ubuntu 14.04. The installation was smooth and everything seemed to be working pretty fine, but the wireless card wasn't.
The weirdest part is that I was using dual boot, so I had ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8 in the same machine so I tried to boot into Ubuntu to find a solution for teh wireless card problem and the wifi was not working on windows anymore :)
I tryed EVERYTHING to make it work (clean format with only W8 again, 2 times) and nothing worked. So now the problem is with windows and Ubuntu. When I check the driver, it says that is working properly but when I run the diagnosis in windows I see actually taht the drivers are ok but it says that the radio is turned off. I've tried really EVERYTHING and nothing seems to be working.
Did anyone have this problem before?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you by adding the output of `sudo lspci |grep Network` to your question!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have hardware switch for the wi-fi. According to http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/yoga2_ug_en.pdf - page 27.

Can you try that ?

Cheers!

Comment: Hey there! Thank you for the answer but that didn't work. I don't know what else to do!