# Intel Wireless-N 7260 dropping connection

Tags: wireless, 14.04, iwlwifi

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro running 14.04 which according to dmesg has a Intel Wireless-N 7260. The wifi is not working correctly. Every 15 minutes or so it will ether get really slow or drop connection altogether. I have found many other questions about this same issue but the solution has always been to upgrade the firmware and I have the latest.

```
> dmesg|grep wifi                                                  
[    2.069093] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: irq 60 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.075970] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.104994] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144
[    2.105153] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
```

Comment: If you find a solution  to this, I would like to add it to my install guide at http://askubuntu.com/a/485632/34298

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a carbon X1 gen2. The only solution that worked, was to download and install a new kernel. Download the following packages from

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17-rc2-utopic

linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-lowlatency_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_amd64.deb
linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_all.deb
linux-image-3.17.0-031700rc2-lowlatency_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_amd64.deb

Type the command below on the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/linux-*
```

After that reboot with the new kernel.