# Tap to click - short mouse movements registering as a click

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, click-policy, tap-to-click

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, on a Lenovo y410p Ideapad, and I'm having an issue where my mouse movements are registering as a tap even when I've actually moved my cursor. For instance, maybe I have the cursor 100 pixels away from something and I move the cursor quickly to the target. When I lift my finger, Ubuntu thinks I've clicked.

I'm guessing there's a time thresh hold for how long the touchpad can be engaged, and if the movement is less than that amount of time it registers as a click? If so, I'd like to shorten this thresh hold. But maybe it doesn't work like that?

It's really annoying, since any small movement of the mouse usually results in a click, often closing tabs or windows unintentionally.

Comment: What about decreasing the pointer speed?  It's under the Mouse & Touchpad section of the settings. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/raring-mouse-settings.jpg

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that solves the issue. Yeah it would make me have to spend more time moving the cursor but the problem would still be there in principal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this also helps here:

Edit the file

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

And edit the "touchpad catchall" section, so it will look like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "touchpad catchall"
Driver "synaptics"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

Option "FingerLow"              "46"
Option "FingerHigh"             "46"
Option "ClickFinger1"           "1"
Option "ClickFinger2"           "2"
Option "ClickFinger3"           "3"
Option "TapButton1"             "1"
Option "TapButton2"             "2"
Option "TapButton3"             "3"
Option "AreaBottomEdge"         "85%"
Option "SoftButtonAreas"        "60% 0 85% 0 40% 60% 85% 0" # Btn2 LRTB - Btn3 LRTB
Option "EmulateMidButtonTime"   "75"
EndSection
```

(source: http://memobadz.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/lenovo-yoga-pro-2-on-ubuntu/ )

Try some of the tips from here:

[Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro/485632#485632)

Comment: Hmm, the comments at the top of the file warn against editing the file, are you sure it's a good idea?

>DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.

Comment: You should try it, I used it for nearly a year now without problems with my Touchpad. And if the distribution changes it again, you know where to find the settings (here)

Comment: Yes, try it and if it doesn't help, you can fiddle around with `synclient` to find the right settings