# How to install Ubuntu Touch on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

The title pretty much says it all...  I'd like to know if there's a simple way of installing Ubuntu Touch on the Yoga 2 Pro?  I've already ran Ubuntu 14.04 on it via my thumb drive but I'd really like to have Ubuntu Touch on it so I can give it to my niece as a Christmas present.

Comment: Try this, don't know if it will work: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-desktop-next/daily-live/current/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro](http://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro)

Comment: you might try this, since it is the same as the ubuntu touch tablet interface right now: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/unity-8-desktop-preview-session-14-04