# Micro-HDMI to VGA adapter does not work with Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro

Tags: lenovo, hdmi, yoga-2

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my new Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro (following the receipt from [Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro)) and all works fine except the micro-HDMI to VGA adapter, to conect to external displays.

I tried with 2 different adapters (one of them is the Lindy no 38193) and the signal is not sent to external display. When I plug the adapter to the laptop, I get the following messages in syslog:

```
Oct 31 23:42:45 eris kernel: [17881.449366] usb 2-6: USB disconnect, device number 22
Oct 31 23:42:46 eris kernel: [17882.073165] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
Oct 31 23:42:46 eris kernel: [17882.204575] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=2047, idProduct=0855
Oct 31 23:42:46 eris kernel: [17882.204579] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 31 23:42:46 eris kernel: [17882.204581] usb 2-6: Product: Lenovo Yoga    
Oct 31 23:42:46 eris kernel: [17882.204583] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: Invensense
Oct 31 23:42:46 eris kernel: [17882.204585] usb 2-6: SerialNumber: 2344846F24000200
Oct 31 23:42:46 eris kernel: [17882.204727] usb 2-6: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 160 microframes
Oct 31 23:42:46 eris kernel: [17882.204731] usb 2-6: ep 0x1 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 160 microframes
Oct 31 23:42:46 eris mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 23: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6"
Oct 31 23:42:46 eris mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 23 was not an MTP device
```

Someone can help me to find the solution please?

Comment: I can only see USB and MTP related messages, none related to the graphics stack, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The Yoga 2 Pro has a serious design flaw that prevents most micro HDMI cables from working properly, see this thread for a workaroud:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Yoga-Flex-Laptops-and/Yoga-2-Pro-micro-HDMi-issue-SOLVED/td-p/1297269

(basically you have to modify the connector so that the metal part becomes longer and makes proper contact)