# Lenovo Yoga pro 2 on 14.04, wifi stopped connecting

Tags: wireless, lenovo

My Yoga stopped connecting to the WiFi network.

I did everything as described in this answer by rubo77: 
[Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro)

```
sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop
sudo service network-manager restart
```

It worked like a charm for a couple of weeks. Then yesterday I suddenly was not able to connect to the wifi (although the network manager shows all the available networks).

I tried restarting the network-manager. The ideapad_laptop mod is not active.

Where to look now to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

do a "rfkill list" from the terminal.   This will show all your available bluetooth and wireless devices.  Ensure that the device which you are using for wifi has not been blocked.  If it is blocked run the following at the terminal rfkill unblock n where n is the device number on the list of rfkill.    ie. rfkill unblock 1.  If 1 is the number on the list corresponding to the wireless adapter

Comment: My rfkill said that nothing is blocked