# External 4k Monitor on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro

Tags: lenovo, external-monitor

Do you have any experience with a 4k monitor at the Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro?

It has an Intel Core i5 4200U and an Intel HD Graphics 4400 card with a mini HDMI port.

I am interested in buying a UHD (3840x2160) external Monitor and use it mainly for office work on my Yoga so 30Hz would be enough for a start.

Comment: We can verify it from the processor specifications page of intel as "Max Resolution " : [https://ark.intel.com/products/75459/Intel-Core-i5-4200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_60-GHz](https://ark.intel.com/products/75459/Intel-Core-i5-4200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_60-GHz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using it with a AMH A399U 3840x2160 monitor with a microHDMI–HDMI cable.  Getting 30Hz.

### Hardware

The HDMI connection seems somewhat sensitive — at some points some of my cables and/or one of the 2 HDMI ports on monitor didn't work at 4K.  I'm unable to say if the laptop, the cables or the monitor were to blame.  But overall I've settled on a connection that works.

- Apparently the Yoga's HDMI port is [slightly too deep for some cables, can be fixed by shaving off some plastic](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Yoga-2-Pro-micro-HDMi-issue-SOLVED/td-p/1297269).  I haven't tried that but I can confirm moving the cable (any of several I tried) easily disconnects it.

On frequency: My monitor claims 60Hz via HDMI 2.0 and DisplayPort; the Yoga 2 Pro is only capable of 30Hz over its HDMI 1.4 (or 1.3?).
(IIUC HDMI 2.0 is not coming to laptops anytime soon, except maybe via nVidia cards.)

On MST / single-stream: I think my monitor uses MST to achieve 4K (pretends to be 2 screens).  This is invisible to me — all software treats it as one video output.  Can't say if it will work with newer single-stream monitors (don't know if Yoga can send single stream nor if all such monitors also accept MST).  I think that's a hardware—hardware question, so a report from a Windows user for your specific monitor should be enough.

The only non-HDMI way to get 4K out of the Yoga is via USB3 -> DisplayPort or USB3 -> HDMI adapters; I haven't tried any and I'm not sure there are any exist with linux drivers ([Pluggable](http://plugable.com/2014/03/06/displaylink-usb-2-0-graphics-adapters-on-linux-2014-edition) are fantastical about linux  and but none of their 4K adapters does).  Also, I think they all use lossy compression to fit USB3 bandwidth.

### Performance

We're using it for reading and coding, and some movie watching.  The Haswell GPU is definitely **not** enough for 3D gaming at 4K.

4K streaming from Youtube doesn't work well.  Left to "auto" it settles on 1080p / 1440p.  Not sure if it's network speed (10–20Mbps here) or decoding speed but I'm resorting to `youtube-dl` and then playing locally.

4K decoding in Gnome Videos app and MPlayer seems to be smooth; VLC tends to struggle.  However there's constant **screen tearing**.  I suspect that's resolvable, haven't looked into it yet.

### Software configuration

- Turning off the internal display and enabling the HDMI just worked.
- So did extending the desktop — half here half there (I did it vertically; don't remember if there was a horizontal width limitation or I just wanted one on top of the other).  In any case, due to the Yoga screen's very high pixel density, it was an awkward setup.  (Per-screen UI scaling is practically non-existant in linux yet.)
- Touching things on the laptop's screen is sometimes nice, so I settled on a config showing same desktop on both screens.  The resolutions are not that different, so I'm set it to draw at 4K and scale down for the internal screen, using this command:

  ```
  xrandr --output HDMI1 -s 3840x2160 --transform none --pos 0x0 --output eDP1 -s 3200x1800 --scale-from 3840x2160 --pos 0x0
  ```

  [https://github.com/cben/myenv/blob/master/bin/4k]

Comment: Great, so it works. What about the "low" refresh rate of 30? Do you (or some co-workers with perfect eyes) recognise any lags when working on this screen. Maybe scrolling?

Comment: Yes, there is perceptible jerkiness on things like scrolling.  But I agree with http://tiamat.tsotech.com/4k-is-for-programmers-redux that it's totally worth the extra pixels.  [Counter-opinion: http://blog.bruchez.name/2014/03/why-i-am-returning-my-seiki-39-4k.html].  Idea: try a 30Hz mode on your current computer to see how it feels.  That said, since you're buying *now*, why not consider 60Hz options.  Displays with 60Hz are about same price (and a long-term investment) so no-brainer.  With laptops, look for DisplayPort output and Broadwell or Skylake CPU (still not a guarantee!)

Answer (score 1):

I connected dell UHD 4K monitor to Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro laptop. Then pressed window key+P key. Selected external monitor only. I got 4K signal at 29HZ. For regular work it is fine.

Comment: How did you connect to the monitor? With HDMI?

Answer (score 1):

Well according to Intel ark, it isn't specified to be able to output a resolution over 3280x2000, so I'm pretty sure 4K is going to be a bad idea, if it works at all. This system is prone to running warm, and 4K wouldn't be very comfy for the iGpu even doing menial tasks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your exact processor type.  the Y-Processor series only support 24Hz on HDMI.  Have a look at the [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics) website...

Comment: So it will be U-Processors: 3200 x 2000 @ 60 Hz, 3840 x 2160 @ 30 Hz

Comment: Then you're fine and you can accept my answer as correct.  :-)
On the other hand: this is something that I have not tested myself and is purely based on the information provided by Intel...  :P  >:)

Comment: I will wait if someone has got experience with a certain monitor model.

Comment: @rubo77: So? Still waiting for an additional answer **;-)** or was the above the best you got?  If yes, ☑ **:-)**

Comment: Still waiting. I want to be sure before i buy