# Screen rotation on Lenovo Yoga 2 (not Pro)

Tags: screen, lenovo, touchscreen, rotate-monitor, yoga-2

How does one enable (automatic -if possible) screen rotation support for a Lenovo Yoga 2 13 running Ubuntu?

The solutions I have tried that were intended for the Yoga 2 Pro and the Yoga 13 (e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro), [here](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/lenovo_yoga_2_pro) and [here](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/lenovo_yoga_13)) do not seem to work. I am running Ubuntu 14.10 64 bits. Thanks in advance!