# Ubuntu 20.04 keeps crashing, read-only flie system etc

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, ssd, windows-10, crash

I have tried installing **Ubuntu 20.04** in **dual boot** with Windows 10 on my 5 years old **Lenovo flex 2 Pro-15 laptop**:

- Intel Core i7-5500U (2,4 Ghz, 2 cores)
- 8 GB RAM - original
- NVIDIA GeForce 840M 1GB + Intel HD Graphics 5500 1GB
- disc upgraded to ADATA SU650 (960GB) SSD

I have installed Win10 without any issues. First installation of Ubuntu **ended with an error message**, but I was able to boot Ubuntu and log myself in.
First thing I have noticed were **missing icons** of applications. When I tried to open terminal or Firefox (I did not try to open any other app), the whole system **froze and then crashed** after a few minutes.

I have **reinstalled both systems** (Windows 10 and Ubuntu), this time without an error message, Ubuntu looked fine, but it **crashed again** few minutes after I opened terminal.

I have tried opening virtual console and found out it is full of: `...Failed to write entry...Read-only filesystem`
Updating firmware of SSD did not help. Next, I found solution including Kernel update, but I cannot access Firefox and it **does not recognize any USB Flash-drive**.

Is there any solution or should I just give up and keep only Win10 on my laptop?

Comment: What is a "virtual console"? What is the original error you got that were trying to fix with the Kernel update? It seems like your hardware is not very Linux friendly, but there are people who have managed to run Ubuntu on it. Have you looked at this post? https://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro

Comment: Well, I have just experienced similar crash in Windows 10 after installing latest Nvidia driver and now I am stuck on black screen after automatic restart, so it might be a HW problem.
For the record, I have found on some websites the ctrl+alt+f3 shortcut to access “virtual console”, so I thought it is called that way. Never mind.
And sadly, I do not remember what the original error was about. The Kernel update was supposed to fix the “read-only file system”.